# How is the String value passed to the updateText() method?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

Tinkering with `RxJava` for the first time, I have created an Rx chain to listen to a change in state of String object :

```
 observable=Observable
  .defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableSource<String> call() throws Exception {
      return(Observable.just(query()));
    }
  })
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .map(this::prettify)
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .cache();
```

Here prettify is :

```
private String prettify(String raw) {
Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonElement json=new JsonParser().parse(raw);

return(gson.toJson(json));
}
```

Now, I created a subscriber to `observable` :

```
sub=observable.subscribe(
  this::updateText,
  error -> Toast
    .makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show()
);
```

But what I couldn't help understand is how the value is passed to the `updateText` method :

```
private void updateText(String text) {
((TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.result)).setText(text);
}
```

The method `updateText` simply works, but my question is how does it get the String value? Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply lambda expression

```
sub=observable.subscribe(
   this::updateText,
   error -> Toast
     .makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
     .show()
);
```

In `this::updateText` called your method `updateText(String text)`

In kind extended version it looks like 
`.subscribe( result -> updateText(result), ....`